# caliburn.micro how to load and bind view for viewmodel runtime

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am building an application that requires theme support. So I want to supply views folder run time.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShell>
{
    CompositionContainer _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// By default, we are configure to use MEF
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Configure()
    {
         //view locator code get views from file and and binding it to viewmodel run time.
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to ship several different DLLs, each with its own copy of your views, and at runtime you'll decide which one to load? If not, you'll need to clarify what you mean by "supply views folder run time".

Comment: @JoeWhite I want to supply Views in xaml only. I will not put in dll. SO when program will starts it should load all views from xaml files.

Comment: You did not provide enough details.  Do you need to switch themes after startup dynamically?  Or just when your application restarts?  This will determine which route you will need to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Caliburn, you can create a customized IConventionManager or tweek the implementation (DefaultConventionManager) to change the way the framework finds the View folder at runtime.

In fact views should not necessarily be in Views folder and you can modify this default behavior as this is just the default Convention. The best way to implement this interface is to check the default implementation.

Answer (score 4):

A better tweak would be to use this way (implemented in Caliburn but not the Micro one). http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/265502

First of all you need to define an attribute used to store the relevant data used to discover the view:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class ViewAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object Context { get; set; }

    public Type ViewType { get; private set; }

    public ViewAttribute(Type viewType)
    {
        ViewType = viewType;
    }
}
```

Attach it to your View Model.

```
[View(typeof(MyView))]
public class MyViewModel : Screen
```

Then, you need to change the LocateTypeForModelType in your bootstrapper to something like this:

```
void Initialize()
{
    var baseLocate = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType;

    ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) =>
    {
        var attribute = modelType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ViewAttribute), false).OfType<ViewAttribute>().Where(x => x.Context == context).FirstOrDefault();
        return attribute != null ? attribute.ViewType : baseLocate(modelType, displayLocation, context);
    };
}
```